# Which package provides ksysguard in Kubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kde

Which package provides `ksysguard` for Kubuntu 22.04? I need it for [plasma-applet-thermal-monitor](https://gitlab.com/agurenko/plasma-applet-thermal-monitor).

Answer (score 1):

While ksysguard is not anymore available in Ubuntu 22.04, its backend sensor packages are still [available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ksysguard).

```
sudo apt install libksysguardformatter1 libksysguardsensorfaces1 libksysguardsensors1 libksysguardsystemstats1
```

Comment: If this doesn't fix to show fans in fan speed widget, is this really not possible anymore? Or was there something else in ksysguard that could have provided this data?

Comment: I really don't know. Please ask a new question